# Kubernetes Application Level Logging

Tags: python, kubernetes, logging, logstash, fluentd

What are the best available options for application-level logging from Kubernetes? I want to write logs from multiple instances of python applications to a single file in a shared location.

Comment: Logging to stdout in json format. Scraping the logs (e.g through filebeat) from the compute nodes, and feeding this input into a logging stack (e.g. ELK). Scraping the logs from the compute nodes gives the scraping service (in this case: filebeat) the possibility to enhance the log data with additional metadata (e.g. namespace name, pod name, pod labels, ...)

Comment: @Turing85 This requires additional multiple pods to monitor a cluster with multiple nodes ?..

Comment: Scraping from the compute nodes is usually done through a daemonset, i.e. one pod per compute node. In the example above, filebeat would be deployed as daemonset.

Comment: @Turing85 does the logs kept to keep the container alive count as the stdout logs? Say if Nginx Pod is running with the last command of tail -f *.log

Comment: I do not understand the question. The only consideration would be to log in json format, although this is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Turing85 You are telling about node-level logging. I want to work on Application level logging. Such as directly exposing logs from the application to some centralized shared storage.

Comment: @ARJUNVPANKAJAKSHAN No, I am talking about pod logs, scraped from the node's file system. As stated above, I would heavily recommend to scrape the pod logs from the node for additional metadata enhancement. We can also send logs explicitly from applications to the stack (e.g. through `GELF`), but we would either miss metadata information, or would have to add them manually to the sent logs.